# Noun Clause in Apposition of Adjective Clause?

Tags: difference, adjectives

In Nesfield's Outline of English Grammar (the McMillan Press Ltd, London and Basingstoke, 1978) he identifies the noun clause in the following sentence:
The rumor that he is sick is false.
I see no reason why "that he is sick" is a noun clause in apposition (as Nesfield says it is) and not an adjective clause modifying "rumor."  What am I failing to see in this example?

Comment: A grammar originally published in [1901](https://books.google.com/books?id=t2UwAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA87&lpg=PA87&dq=%22Nesfield%27s+Outline+of+English+Grammar%22+edition&source=bl&ots=D5liXV4iIw&sig=CkCXd88dp8caHIMPC-gIMR0xs6s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9kYOhx8LPAhXEMSYKHZ3AAd0Q6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22Nesfield%27s%20Outline%20of%20English%20Grammar%22%20edition&f=false) can be expected to include a number of oddities. Can you provide a link to an online version, or enter the salient portion of Nesfield's text by using the [edit] link below your question?

Comment: @P.E.Dant Alas, it is not an "oddity"; it was still standard doctrine in the grammar I was taught in the late 1950s. What **is** odd is that it's lingered in English pedagogy for almost a century; indeed, a high school English teacher who could produce this analysis would probably pride himself on his unusually deep knowledge (unless of course he concealed his eccentric interest in grammar lest he be accused of recidivist elitism).

Comment: @StoneyB I'm sure there are many students even now being taught these things. If not oddities, we can call them with less opprobrium, perhaps, survivals? Or is there a more piquant term?

Comment: @P.E.Dant Zombies?

Comment: @StoneyB i had in mind a term more redolent of what we might call the pedagogical peristalsis that takes up current usages and noisily expels those which have been, uhm, consumed.

Comment: @StoneyB It was different in the states during the 50s. Here it was not the left but the right that might perp-walk a pedagogue to the stocks, and for being a recidivist pinko "Deweyite," rather than an elitist.

Comment: @P.E.Dant --I'm a murrican, albeit by way of being Reconstructed, and I was around for that--but since the '80s it's the NEA and its EdSkool commissars that have repudiated the teaching of even the most conservative grammar.

Comment: @StoneyB I'd forgotten that you are USAian. Where I prepped, we didn't have commissars; we had obersturmführers. It surprises me that we were spared Nesfield.

Comment: Nesfield understood the *that*-clause as an appositive because the *that*-clause was felt to be something held side-by-side with **rumor**.  "The rumor, *namely*, that he is sick..."    Since a *that*-clause can be the subject of a verb, it was felt to have a nominal weight or essence. (That he is sick is only a rumor.) Although the *that*-clause doesn't *rename* **rumor**. it does put a name on it, so to speak; the *that*-clause supplies the nature of the rumor. And that is why you want to call it an *adjective-clause*.

Answer (score 1):

Nesfield's description of this use of what is these days usually called a 'content clause' (*that* + finite clause) as a "noun clause", and your own description of it as an "adjective clause", evidence a rather old-fashioned way of understanding the role played by the clause, in which the morphological category "part of speech" is held to determine a constituent's syntactical role.

The *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Huddleston and Pullum 2002, 1016-1017) gives two convincing reasons for rejecting the traditional analysis.

1. Many of the nouns which license this construction are closely related to  verbs (if not indeed derived from them) which take precisely the same sort of 'content clauses' as complements:

   > the thought that he is sick ... *He thinks that he is sick*
   >   the belief that he is sick ... *I believe that he is sick*
   >   the conclusion that he is sick ...  *The doctors have concluded that he is sick*

   In some cases there are even adjectives from the same etymological root which take the same complements:

   > He feared he was sick.
   >   His fear that he was sick ...
   >   He was afraid that he was sick ...

   There is no reason why a constituent having the same sense and form and bearing the same relation to the word which licenses it should bear a different label simply because that word changes its form or the syntactic role it plays.
2. In any case, the notion of apposition is wholly unjustifiable. An appositive "renames" the term it is apposed to; but *that he is sick* is itself neither a belief nor a thought nor a conclusion nor a fear—nor a rumour—it is what is believed, thought, concluded, feared or rumored.

I concur with *CGEL* that "it is a complement, licensed by the head of the VP, NP or AdjP in which it occurs".

Comment: Here is a demonstration that "squishy" need not mean "imprecise."

Answer (score 0):

The clause *that he is sick* defines the Noun *rumor*. A clause that performs the job of identifying or defining a Noun is actually in apposition; this is not an Adjective Clause.  When you are confused, just put a question with *what* to the Verb of the dependent clause, in this case: what he is? the answer is *sick*, not *rumour*. Thus, the clause in question is not an Adjective Clause.  Only a Noun Clause can be in apposition to a Noun.